# Extract from XML response with multiple child nodes using PLSQL in different set of rows

Tags: xml, oracle, soap

This is related to SOAP xml response, and fetching the data via Oracle PLSQL.

The SOAP xml response is this (which contains multiple child nodes in contacts parent node) -

```
<firstName>ABC</firstName>
<lastname>XYZ</lastName>
<gender>M</gender>
<service @effdate='2015-02-02'>ACTIVE</service>

<contacts>
<contactTier><contactId>CT001</contactId><contactName>Core Contact</contactName></contactTier>
<contactTier><contactId>CT015</contactId><contactName>Contact 2</contactName></contactTier>
</contacts>
```

I have this select query for my ORACLE APEX report, which directly utilizes the SOAP xml response and displays the fields -

```
    select
    quota.firstName
   ,quota.lastName 
   ,quota.gender
   ,quota.service
   ,quota.contacts.extract('//contactTier//contactName//text()','xmlns="http://grocery.org/schema/quota"').getstringval() as name
   ,quota.contacts.extract('//contactTier//contactName//text()','xmlns="http://grocery.org/schema/quota"').getstringval() as ID


   from
   xmltable (
      xmlnamespaces(
         'http://grocery.org/schema/quota/service'
         ,'http://grocery.org/schema/quota'
         )
   ,'for $i in /*/*/*/quota/quota return /$i'
   passing (select xmlresp from mytable where id = 'SOAPID3')
   columns
       service                xmltype         path '/quota/v61:service'      
      ,contacts               xmltype          path '/quota/v61:contacts'        
      ,first_name             varchar2(2000)   path '/quota/v61:firstName'
      ,last_name              varchar2(2000)   path '/quota/lastName'
      ,gender                 varchar2(2000)   path '/quota/gender'
     ) quota ;
```

My concern is that the extract function concatenates the contactNames (from contacts node) and returns them as part of one single row.

I need the query to return as many number of rows as there are contactTiers.

(Please ignore the xmlnamespace and other aspects if they seem wrong..)
Hope that makes sense..

Looking forward to all replies.
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return as many rows as there are contacts, then you'll probably want more programmatic control over the XML parsing.  You could do something like the following, which outputs 1 or more rows per employee (up to how many contacts he/she has).

First, the basic emp table:

```
create table my_emp
(
    empno number,
    ename varchar2(50),
    job varchar2(50),
    hiredate date,
    contactid number,
    contactname varchar2(50)
)
```

Now, the PL/SQL block to process some XML:

```
declare
  --l_bfile   BFILE;
  l_clob    CLOB;
  l_parser  dbms_xmlparser.Parser;
  l_doc     dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
  l_nl      dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  l_cnl      dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  l_n       dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
  l_cn       dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
  l_temp    VARCHAR2(1000);

  TYPE tab_type IS TABLE OF my_emp%ROWTYPE;
  t_tab  tab_type := tab_type();
BEGIN

  -- this clob could be a big XML document loaded from a file (or from a SOAP service)
  -- just using the following as a test document
  l_clob := '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<employees>
  <employee>
    <empno>123</empno>
    <ename>SMITH</ename>
    <job>CLERK</job>
    <hiredate>17-DEC-1980</hiredate>
    <contacts>
      <contactTier>
        <contactId>100</contactId>
        <contactName>JOE BLOW</contactName>
      </contactTier>
      <contactTier>
        <contactId>200</contactId>
        <contactName>MARY JANE</contactName>
      </contactTier>
    </contacts>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <empno>7499</empno>
    <ename>ALLEN</ename>
    <job>SALESMAN</job>
    <hiredate>20-FEB-1981</hiredate>
    <contacts>
        <contactTier>
          <contactId>300</contactId>
          <contactName>DONALD DUCK</contactName>
        </contactTier>
    </contacts>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <empno>1234</empno>
    <ename>JONES</ename>
    <job>SALESMAN</job>
    <hiredate>20-FEB-1982</hiredate>
  </employee>
</employees>';

  -- for implicit date conversions
  dbms_session.set_nls('NLS_DATE_FORMAT','''DD-MON-YYYY''');

  -- Create a parser.
  l_parser := dbms_xmlparser.newParser;

  -- Parse the document 
  dbms_xmlparser.parseClob(l_parser, l_clob);
  l_doc := dbms_xmlparser.getDocument(l_parser);

  -- list of all the employee nodes in the document
  l_nl := dbms_xslprocessor.selectNodes(dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_doc),'/employees/employee');

  FOR cur_emp IN 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getLength(l_nl)-1  LOOP
    l_n := dbms_xmldom.item(l_nl, cur_emp);


    t_tab.extend;
    dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_n,'empno',t_tab(t_tab.last).empno);
    dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_n,'ename',t_tab(t_tab.last).ename);
    dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_n,'job',t_tab(t_tab.last).job);
    dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_n,'hiredate',t_tab(t_tab.last).hiredate);

    -- list of all contacts for this employee
    l_cnl := dbms_xslprocessor.selectNodes(l_n, 'contacts/contactTier');

    -- add first contact, if any
    l_cn := dbms_xmldom.item(l_cnl, 0);
    dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_cn,'contactId',t_tab(t_tab.last).contactid);
    dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_cn,'contactName',t_tab(t_tab.last).contactname);

    -- add all other contacts, repeating employee info for each row
    for cur_contact in 1 .. dbms_xmldom.getLength(l_cnl)-1  LOOP
        l_cn := dbms_xmldom.item(l_cnl, cur_contact);
        t_tab.extend;
        dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_n,'empno',t_tab(t_tab.last).empno);
        dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_n,'ename',t_tab(t_tab.last).ename);
        dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_n,'job',t_tab(t_tab.last).job);
        dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_n,'hiredate',t_tab(t_tab.last).hiredate);
        dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_cn,'contactId',t_tab(t_tab.last).contactid);
        dbms_xslprocessor.valueOf(l_cn,'contactName',t_tab(t_tab.last).contactname);
    end loop;

  END LOOP;

  -- Insert data into the emp table from the table collection.
  --FORALL i IN t_tab.first .. t_tab.last
  --  INSERT INTO my_emp VALUES t_tab(i);
  --COMMIT; 

  ----------------------------------------
  -- use the following for testing to stdout
  ----------------------------------------
  for i in t_tab.first .. t_tab.last
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(t_tab(i).empno || ', ' || t_tab(i).ename || ', ' || t_tab(i).job || ', ' || t_tab(i).hiredate || ', ' || t_tab(i).contactid || ', ' || t_tab(i).contactname);
  end loop;
  -----------------------------------------

  -- Free any resources
  dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_clob);
  dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(l_doc);
 dbms_xmlparser.freeParser(l_parser);


EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_clob);
    dbms_xmlparser.freeParser(l_parser);
    dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(l_doc);
END;
```

The output is:

```
123, SMITH, CLERK, 17-DEC-1980, 100, JOE BLOW
123, SMITH, CLERK, 17-DEC-1980, 200, MARY JANE
7499, ALLEN, SALESMAN, 20-FEB-1981, 300, DONALD DUCK
1234, JONES, SALESMAN, 20-FEB-1982, ,
```

Also see [this article](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/parse-xml-documents-9i.php) , the site is a good reference for all things Oracle.

Comment: Hi @tbone, the response xml is just the way it is. I do not have control over it..
I even tried using EXTRACTVALUE (xmlnode, required_path, xmlnamespace) but I get the error "ORA-19025 ExtractValue returns value of only one node"

Comment: Hi, I mean more control over parsing the XML itself (in other words, I'm not sure if you can do what you're asking using just xmltable , but using dbms_xmldom means more options for you in how you handle the XML you get)